# android MVP & DI

Tags: dependency-injection, mvp, dagger-2

I am creating an android app and I write following classes and interface and codes .Because I try to use MVP pattern , But now I am not sure that my codes are standard or not ?
should I use Dagger2 for Di or should not?
model , presenter class are below:

```
public class ChangePasswordModel{

    public void saveChange(final String oldPass, final String newPass, final ChangePasswordCallback callback) {
    /*in real world it change password with API*/
        callback.onDo();
 } }
```

my presenter is :

```
public class ChangePasswordPresenter{
 private ChangePasswordContract.View mView;//this is an interface to interact with Activity

public ChangePasswordPresenter(ChangePasswordContract.View mView) {
    this.mView = mView;
}

public void pSaveChange(String oldPass, String newPass) {
 ChangePasswordModel model = new ChangePasswordModel();
    model.saveChange(oldPass, newPass, new ChangePasswordCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onDo() {
            mView.showMessage("password Changed");
        }
 });
}
```

}

1. Do I implemented **MVP** correctly?
2. Should I use **Dagger2** for DI? why?

Comment: check post its a kind of related to MVP dagger and retrofit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39957632/dagger-2-not-injecting-in-interface-type

Comment: You can take a look at this sample project which has been developed using Dagger, MVP and there are also some test available:
http://github.com/mmirhoseini/fyber_mobile_offers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample codes that you mentioned in your question is a correct implementation of MVP which can get improved by some changes.

The best practice is a mixture of **Dagger**, **MVP**, **RxJava**, **Retrofit** and **Mock** tests which improve the quality and readability of your project. **MVP** helps you with a clean and separate layered code and **RxJava** will help with wiring different layers up together and **Dagger2** can really helps you with managing dependencies and also make your Mocking in test easy.

You can take a look at this sample project repo on my Github which has been developed using Dagger, MVP and there are also some test available:

> http://github.com/mmirhoseini/fyber_mobile_offers

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be improved in my opinion. You Model class must be a concrete object class however your `ChangePasswordModel` contains `saveChange()` method that have no idea why it's calling a `callback`. This logic must be implemented in Presenter class.

Basically process of following MVP design pattern is as follows:

1. create a package based on your screen. Let's say you have a Signup screen. Then create a package, `<your.main.package>.signupscreen`.
2. Create three classes of SignupActivity, SignupView(this is interface), SignupPresenter.

`SignupView` interface:

```
interface SignUpView {
    String getFirstName();
    String getLastName();
    String getEmailAddress();
    String getPassword();
}
```

`SignupActivity` implements `SignUpView` and holds a reference of SignupPresenter.

```
public class SignUpActivity implements SignUpView {
    @Inject
    public Service mService;

    SignUpPresenter mSignUpPresenter;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        mSignUpPresenter = new SignUpPresenter(mService, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (mSignUpPresenter != null) {
            mSignUpPresenter.onStop();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getFirstName() {
        return etFirstName.getText().toString().trim();
    }

    @Override
    public String getLastName() {
        return etLastName.getText().toString().trim();
    }

    @Override
    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return etEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return etPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    }
}
```

And finally `SignupPresenter` class:

```
class SignUpPresenter implements SignUpCallback {

    private final Service service;
    private final SignUpView view;
    private CompositeSubscription subscriptions;

    SignUpPresenter(Service service, SignUpView view) {
        this.service = service;
        this.view = view;
        this.subscriptions = new CompositeSubscription();
    }

    void onStop() {
        subscriptions.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

This is very basic implementation of Activity based on MVP. I do recommend to have a look at this awesome doc regard MVP, Retrofit and Dagger 2, [A Simple Android Apps with MVP, Dagger, RxJava, and Retrofit](https://medium.com/@nurrohman/a-simple-android-apps-with-mvp-dagger-rxjava-and-retrofit-4edb214a66d7#.ue8s6wh6p)