# Dagger 2 not injecting in interface type

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I an trying to inject a field in an interface type which is implemented by a class.

Here is what i have done so far.

These are view interface:

```
public interface PostView extends View, ListView<Post>, EmptyView<String> {
}
public interface View {

    public void showProgressIndicator();

    public void hideProgressIndicator();

    public void onSuccess();

    public void onFailure();

    public void onFailure(String message);
}

public interface ListView<E> {

    public void onListItems(List<E> items,
            int pageNum,
            int pageSize,
            boolean next);

}

public interface EmptyView<E> {

    public void onEmpty(E e);

    public void onEmpty(String message);
}
```

Components:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = ApiModule.class)
public interface ApiComponent {

    Api provideApi();

}

@UserScope
@Component(dependencies = ApiComponent.class, modules = PostModule.class)
public interface PostComponent {

    PostPresenter providePostPresenter();

    void inject(NetworkTest networkTest);
}
```

Modules:

```
@Module
public class ApiModule {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ApiModule.class.getSimpleName());

    private final String baseUrl;

    public ApiModule(String baseUrl) {
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    boolean provideIsLoggerEnabled() {
        logger.info("proviedIsLoggerEnabled()");
        return true;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient(boolean logEnabled) {
        logger.info(" provideOkHttpClient(logEnabled)");
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        Interceptor requestInterceptor = new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                return chain.proceed(chain.request());
            }
        };
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
                .addNetworkInterceptor(interceptor);
        return builder.build();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Api provideApi(OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
        logger.info("provideApi");
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        return retrofit.create(Api.class);
    }

}

@Module
public class PostModule {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PostModule.class.getSimpleName());
    private final PostView postView;

    public PostModule(PostView postView) {
        this.postView = postView;
    }

    @Provides
    @UserScope
    PostService providePostService(Api api) {
        logger.info("Provider post with api now");
        return new PostService(api);
    }

    @Provides
    @UserScope
    PostPresenter providePostPresenter(PostService service) {
        logger.info("Providing presenter with service now");
        return new PostPresenter(postView, service);
    }
}
```

Presenter:

```
public class PostPresenter extends AbstractPresenter {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PostPresenter.class.getSimpleName());
    private PostView postView;
    private PostService postService;

    public PostPresenter(PostView postView, PostService postService) {
        this.postView = postView;
        this.postService = postService;
    }

    @Override
    protected View getView() {
        logger.info("Getting view");
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    public void getPosts() {
        logger.info("Getting posts ");
        Call<List<Post>> posts = this.postService.getPosts();
        postView.showProgressIndicator();
        posts.enqueue(new Callback<List<Post>>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Post>> call, Response<List<Post>> rspns) {
                postView.onListItems(rspns.body(), 1, 25, true);
                postView.hideProgressIndicator();
                postView.onSuccess();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Post>> call, Throwable thrwbl) {
                onApiCallError(thrwbl);
                postView.hideProgressIndicator();
            }
        });
    }
}

public abstract class AbstractPresenter {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AbstractPresenter.class.getSimpleName());

    protected abstract View getView();

    /*
     * General indication whether api call stated or not.
     */
    protected void onApiCallStart() {
        logger.info("Api call started");
        View v = getView();
        if (v != null) {
            v.showProgressIndicator();
        }
    }

    protected void onApiCallEnd() {
        logger.info("Api call finished");
        View v = getView();
        if (v != null) {
            v.hideProgressIndicator();
        }
    }

    /*
     * General error handling 
     */
    protected void onApiCallError(Throwable e) {
        logger.info("Api call terminated with error");
        View v = getView();
        if (v != null && e != null) {
            v.onFailure(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

NetworkTest:

```
public class NetworkTest implements PostView {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(NetworkTest.class.getSimpleName());

    private PostComponent component;
    @Inject
    PostPresenter presenter;

    public NetworkTest(ApiComponent apiComponent) {
        component = DaggerPostComponent.builder()
                .apiComponent(apiComponent)
                .postModule(new PostModule(this))
                .build();
    }

    public void init() {
        component.inject(this);
    }

    void showPosts() {
        if (presenter != null) {
            logger.info("Hurray it worked");
            presenter.getPosts();
        } else {
            logger.warning("Alas it failed");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void showProgressIndicator() {
        logger.info("Show progress indicator here");
    }

    @Override
    public void hideProgressIndicator() {
        logger.info("Hide progress indicator here");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        logger.info("Api calls successfull");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure() {
        logger.warning("Api call failure");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(String message) {
        logger.warning(message);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItems(List<Post> items, int pageNum, int pageSize, boolean next) {
        logger.info("List received is: " + new Gson().toJson(items));
    }

    @Override
    public void onEmpty(String e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApiComponent apiComponent = DaggerApiComponent.builder()
                .apiModule(new ApiModule("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/"))
                .build();

        NetworkTest networkTest = new NetworkTest(apiComponent);
        networkTest.init();
        networkTest.showPosts();
    }

}
```

My Problem is when i try to use

```
void inject(NetworkTest networkTest); //It works
void inject(PostView postView); //Doesn't work
```

I want that `PostPresenter` should get Injected in any class who is implementing `PostView`.

But when i do this `@Inject` field return null.
Does anyone have any clue about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetworkTest has an `@Inject` field that Dagger can detect at compile time. PostView does not. Dagger 2 can perform injection on both NetworkTest and PostView, but because PostView has no `@Inject`-annotated methods, there's nothing for Dagger 2 to inject.

If you want to express that arbitrary implementors of PostView can be injected, you should add an `@Inject`-annotated `initialize` or `injectPresenter` method (et al); otherwise, just get/inject concrete types from Dagger so all of their dependencies can be injected at once.

---

As stated in the [Dagger 2 user's guide](http://google.github.io/dagger/) (emphasis mine), "Dagger is a **fully static, compile-time** dependency injection framework for both Java and Android." Unlike with Guice or Spring, Dagger 2 performs no runtime reflection, so (for instance) a generated Component method `inject(PostView)` can only inject fields and methods defined *on PostView or its supertypes*, and not anything defined on a subtype.

In a general sense, I don't think it's reasonable for you to expect (or constrain) your `PostView` interface implementors to require the injection of a Presenter a certain way; if you want to make an explicit presenter-providing lifecycle method, you can do that on PostView without involving Dagger, and that way your classes can be more specific with their dependencies rather than mixing the necessary deps with the "unnecessary-but-included" deps you prescribe.

Comment: Or can u suggest come correction if it seems wrong.

Comment: @sector11 In my answer, I describe that both approaches—adding an `@Inject` method to PostView, or only injecting concrete types—are technically possible, but I like the latter for all the reasons I said in my final paragraph. You'll need to make the engineering decision about which one better suits your use case.

Comment: i understood what you explained with Concrete type as above but i didnt understood providing method to PostView where i can inject in that just a interface. I might be missing something here which i am not aware of. recently started Dagger2

Comment: @sector11 You can add an `@Inject`-annotated method to your interface, and then all of your implementing classes would need to provide an implementation for that method even when empty. Then you could keep your `inject(PostView)` method on your component, and passing in an arbitrary PostView implementation would cause that method to be called. (However, do note that would only handle injection points defined on PostView, and not any fields or methods defined on subclasses.)

Comment: yes concrete implementation looks good. Thanks you for detailed explanation.